# nth-of-type css selector

Tags: selenium, webdriver, css-selectors, selenium-webdriver

Below is a snippet of my HTML page:

```
<td id="Platinum" align="center" width="16%">
    <div></div> 
    <a>link1</a>
</td>
<td></td>
<td id="Platinum" align="center" width="16%">
    <div></div>
    <a>link2</a>
</td>
<td id="Platinum" align="center" width="16%">
    <div></div>
    <a>link3</a>
</td>
```

Here I want to select third td element with id='platinum'

what I tried is `driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#platinum:nth-of-type(3)"));`.

and

`driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("td[id='platinum']:nth-of-type(3)"));`

Both are not working any idea on how to select third td with `id='platinum'`

Comment: Well what browser and what version of Selenium?

Comment: Why are they all sharing the same ID?

Comment: @Arran: I'm using Firefox 11.0 and Selenium 2.28.0

Comment: @BoltClock: I don't know why but they are sharing the same id...

Comment: Element ids must be unique! The site should use a class instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an empty `td` that doesn't have the ID, which is interfering with the `:nth-of-type()` count. The selector means "nth `td` element", not "nth `td` element with `id='platinum'`". The third `td` with that ID is therefore actually the fourth `td` in the entire row.

It's not possible to select the third `td` element with a certain ID using a CSS selector. You should use XPath instead:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[@id='Platinum'][3]"));
```

Comment: By.cssSelector(td[id='platinum']:nth-of-type(1)) is working fine

Comment: That's because it's the first `td` and it has that ID. But it isn't the element that you're looking for in your question, so I'm not sure what your point is.

Answer (score 0):

Well first of all. You can`t have several id with same name. You should use classes. Then you can try it again using same method, but using classes.
The code will looks like this:

```
<td class="Platinum" align="center" width="16%">
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer. What you have said is write but i'm testing the following url http://www.franchising.com/find_a_franchise/ here the items have the above mentiond HTML with same ID

Answer (score 0):

Just to add, if you tried this in JQuery you would possibly get the same result. The "#id" likely shortcuts to use the document.getElementByID() function which will only ever return the first element with the ID, as ID is meant to be unique within a given document.