# Is there a selenium cssSelector equivalent to get the "nth" matching element?

Tags: jquery, selenium, selenium-webdriver, css-selectors

Here is my sample jQuery which returns 10 matching elements on a page:

```
$('input.text-form-field');
```

Since I only need the 3rd element, I used the below and it works fine:

```
$('input.text-form-field').get(2);
```

Can someone suggest a proper selenium cssSelector equivalent to achieve the same result?

Simply using

```
By.cssSelector("input.text-form-field")
```

will fail as it matches against 10 elements on the page !

Any help in this regard would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There isn't a CSS selector for getting the nth match. You'll need XPath.

Comment: Do you mean a selector like: input.text-form-field:nth-child(3) ?

Comment: @Patrick2607: No, he surely means the third input.text-form-field. `input.text-form-field:nth-child(3)` means that input when it is the 3rd child of its parent, which can be true for all 10 matching elements (or none of them).

Comment: something like this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14376263/1719752

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this

```
List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.className("text-form-field"));
for (WebElement element : elements) 
{
element.click(); // iterate or do get(2) for third element
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this can be done using a CSS selector, but you can do it using an XPath.

```
By.XPath("(//input[@class=\"text-form-field\"])[2]")
```